# Error:(106, 20) error: method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity

Tags: java, admob, oncreate

I am having trouble adding Google AdMob code from another project, as it seems that a part of my code also uses onCreate(Bundle).

Here's the part of my project that uses onCreate(Bundle) from the MainActivity.java:

```
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

The part I'm trying to add:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
    Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I am new to java, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are new to Java, try learning about methods themselves. The error is clearly stated, and it is not clear what you've done from these two out of context code blocks, but there cannot be two methods for the same thing

Comment: It is already saying the error you have. You already have a onCreate() method in main activity, and then the code you are copying also have a onCreate() method. It wont be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The part I'm trying to add

You should be adding this part into the *existing* onCreate method, not the entire method body

```
// Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```